# How could I extract an id from a URL?

Tags: javascript, url

I want to know how do I extract an id from a url like this url

https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o

I want to extract just a ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o from this url

Comment: Java to JavaScript is like Ham to Hamster. Please use [edit] option and remove tag of language this question isn't about (currently it is tagged with `javascript` `java` `url`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use searchParams from the url.

```js
const url = "https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o";

const placeid = (new URL(url)).searchParams.get('placeid')
console.log(placeid)
```

Comment: well what I really want is to use such a link to attach it in the Counsel of a page then takes every url that is found and extract the Id

Comment: `Array.from(document.links).filter(lnk => lnk.search).map(lnk => (new URL(lnk)).searchParams.get('placeid')).filter(x=>x)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to return the different parameters as an array and then you can get all the parameters you need (placeid in your case):

```js
var url = "https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o";

function getUrlVars(url) {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function(m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}

console.log(getUrlVars(url)["placeid"]);
```

Comment: well what I really want is to use such a link to attach it in the Counsel of a page then takes every url that is found and extract the Id

Comment: with this you can just call that `getUrlVars` function for each url as `getUrlVars('whatever_url')['placeid']` and you get the `placeid` of that 'whatever_url'. To be fair epascarello answer is also generic and would also work, choose the one that you prefer for your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use "split" javascript function like this:

```
var url = "https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o";
var components = url.split("placeid=");
```

Now you can obtain the id with

```
components[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.
Use `replace()`.

```
var string = "https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ88-l70zRxokRj1h_fvsB40o";
string = string.replace("https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=", "");
```